# Function call for small method will consume for memory or not..... in C#

Tags: c#, jquery, vb.net

I have one question. Instead of writing big method(including big business logic), i preferred to divide this method in small methods and call them in one method because for me it looks so neat and easy to maintain. But my Team Lead said that "*Don't write small methods and call them in one because it consumes more memory while you call small methods.*"  **Is that correct** ?

Please suggest what should i do in this case ? and once again **thank you** for your valuable time

Comment: It is correct - every new function will increase size of call stack. **But** this should be considered as performance problem only on "embedded" software where your memory is limited. In "regular" applications readability and maintainability goes over this kind of optimizations - which have no affect on the user experience.

Comment: Worry about maintainability first. unless you are passing enormous value types as parameters the overhead is insignificant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many factors that come into play here. More context of your project would be required to give any strict conclusions.

Generally speaking though, C#, VB and managed languages in general were devised to prioritize developer productivity over performance. In that light, worrying about method call memory consumption seems questionable.

Additionally, IL-based languages (C#, VB, ...) use a JIT that compiles the intermediate code to CPU-specific assembly in runtime. JIT's unit of work is a method. The bigger the method, the less optimizations JIT can do. Therefore a big method may yield worse performance than many small methods doing the same work. In addition, JIT can also do an optimization called inlining where a small method code is generated inside its caller, eliding the function call altogether.

Function call takes very little memory by C#/VB's terms. Unless you're working in a very constrained environment (e.g. embedded), such optimization doesn't really make sense, especially when not backed by any reasonable arguments.

Answer (score 1):

You are both mistaken.

OOP is built on a concept of divide and conquer so you should divide your method into small methods for the sake of reuse ability and maintainability.

About the memory consumed, I don't think it will consume more memory but this may happen when you create methods for each small task.

So yes divide them into small methods only if need to, with respect of resources and sharing variables.

Comment: thank you @ hassan 
i understand one think from ur concept. we split method when they are need for reusable